# fnGetData() actual content of table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get the content of my table after I edit it but when I check what I get by using fnGetData() is the old content.
Am I missing something? (I'm using DataTables v1.10.8 )

```
function save(){ // it's the function I call after editing the table rows by submiting
     var tableContent = $('#editableTable').dataTable();
     console.log(tableContent.fnGetData()); // here I get the old content
     $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
            url : "ajax",
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                json : JSON.stringify(tableContent.fnGetData())
             }
      });
}
```

Comment: Are you using `fnUpdate()` to update the contents in the table?

Comment: @NiallMitch14: No i'm not using it what does it serve for ?

Answer (score 1):

I've forgot to add these two lines! now it works thanks NiallMitch14 for your comment.

```
var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
oTable.fnUpdate( value, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
```

Comment: No problem :) `fnUpdate()` will update the row in the data table with the updated values.